# How do I center align text in navigation <li> element?

Tags: css

I am doing a PHP project for school and I want my header navigation list text to center, but neither `text-align: center;` or `vertical-align: middle;` works. Any suggestions?

http://ectweb.cs.depaul.edu/AHARDEN2/project/index.php

Comment: To center vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Take off the float:left, add in a margin:0 auto and a width to the nav's ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a width and margin:auto to your style.css on line 241. Remove all the floats that reference your nav and ul.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Fixing the rest of the nav now.

Answer (score 0):

```
body > nav {
    text-align: center;
}

body > nav > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, the best way is usually:

For text:

```
.centredText {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 4em; /* This is whatever size you need each margin to be. */
}
```

For a div or an image (what this sounds like):

```
.centredItem {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then in your HTML, `<div class="centredItem">Stuff</div>`